# Web site does not show ( Says its down) , no user code is called

Tags: c#, asp.net

The site loads app_offline.htm.

The application used to load fine, im not sure whats wrong and im looking for a pointer. Its failing to load on the application. This hosted on the development asp.net server

To get this call stack i have to enable A first chance exception in System.Web.HttpExecption, here is the "console" output

> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in
>   System.Web.dll
>  A first chance
>   exception of type
>   'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in
>   System.Web.dll
>  Additional
>   information: ASP.NET Initialization
>   Error: 
>  A first chance exception
>   of type 'System.Web.HttpException'
>   occurred in System.Web.dll
>   Additional information: ASP.NET
>   Initialization Error:

The call stack for the first execption.

> System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.CheckApplicationEnabled()
>   Line 1269C#
>   System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(System.Web.HttpContext
>   context = {System.Web.HttpContext})
>   Line 579C#
>   System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(System.Web.HttpContext
>   context) Line 652C#
>   System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest
>   wr =
>   {Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Request})
>   Line 1582 + 0x9 bytesC#
>   System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNoDemand(System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest
>   wr) Line 2270C#
>   System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest
>   wr) Line 2256C#

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The presence of 'app_offline.htm" in the root folder will prevent the app from running. Rename the file and it should allow your app to load.

Comment: Beat me to it. :) Check out http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/06/426755.aspx for details.

Comment: Thank you very much, as always a simple thing creating problems for over a week for me.

Answer (score 0):

Is it set up as an "application" in IIS?  With the correct .NET version and all that?